# Use the internet connection of a remote desktop without VPN

Tags: internet, remote-desktop, vpn, remote

I live in Iran, and due to my country's Internet policies, I am unable to use a VPN connection to a server outside the country. Without VPN access, how can I connect to my server outside Iran in order to gain unfiltered access to the Internet?

Comment: Use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/)

Comment: You can't because your  country's Internet policies prevent those solutions.  Tor is included in those polciies.

Answer (score 0):

While most VPNs are actively blocked by the Iranian government, it appears as though several remain available for use. [StrongVPN](http://strongvpn.com/packages_iran.shtml) markets itself specifically to users in Iran, and has received recent, positive reviews from Iranian account holders.

As other users noted, [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) remains an option, though you may be disappointed with its limited bandwidth.